# Should functions used for map() take a reference?

Tags: lambda, rust, closures

Just trying to write a generic `take_samples()` of a function for a list of x.

```
type Real = f32;
type FunctionRR = fn(Real) -> Real;
type ListOfReal = Vec<Real>;

fn take_samples( xs: &ListOfReal, f: FunctionRR ) -> ListOfReal {
    return xs.iter().map( f ).collect();
} 

let ys = take_samples( &xs, |x| x*x );
```

But got the error:

> map expected `fn( &f32 ) -> _` but found `fn ( f32 ) -> _`

In addition, `fn` is a pointer to function. Hence, if I'm not wrong, only functions would be allowed for `take_samples()`.
The general solution would be `Fn` (permitting closures and curried functions):

```
type FunctionRR = dyn Fn( &f32 ) -> f32;
```

Right?

Moreover:

```
 (0..=10).map( |i:i32| i as f32 * 0.1 ).collect();
```

is just fine but

```
 xs.iter().map( |x:f32| x*x ).collect();
```

is not.

Comment: Whether `map()` yields values or references is dependent on the iterator upon which its called: `(0..=10)` yields `i32`s while `xs.iter()` yields `&f32`s. So *"should functions used for map() take a reference in Rust?*" doesn't really have an answer.

Comment: If you want to use a function that takes values, you can use `xs.into_iter()` or `xs.iter().copied()`

Comment: If you're not sure whether said function will be operating on `T`s or `&T`s then you can have it take a `impl std::borrow::Borrow<T>`, which both `T` and `&T` implement. In the case where `T: Copy` it's probably simpler to just use `copied()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devised this solution for the `take_samples()` function, now accepting functions and closures/lambdas and circumventing the `map()` call problem:

```
fn take_samples<T: Fn(Real)->Real>( xs: &ListOfReal, f: T ) 
   -> ListOfReal {

    return xs.iter().map( |x| f(*x) ).collect();
} // ()

fn id( x: Real ) -> Real {
    x
}

fn main() {
    let xs = generate_xs( 0.0, 10.0, 20 );

    let ys = take_samples( &xs, |x| x*x );
    let ys2 = take_samples( &xs, &id );
}
```